# Using xgboost in Pyspark gives ImportError: cannot import name 'JavaPredictionModel'

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, xgboost

This is my first attempt to use xgboost in pyspark so my experience with Java and Pyspark is still in learning phase.

I saw an awesome article in towards datascience with title [PySpark ML and XGBoost full integration tested on the Kaggle Titanic dataset](https://towardsdatascience.com/pyspark-and-xgboost-integration-tested-on-the-kaggle-titanic-dataset-4e75a568bdb) where the author goes through use case of xgboost in pyspark.

I tried to follow the steps but was hit with ImportError.

## Installation

I have downloaded two jar files from maven and put them in the same directory where my notebook is.

- [xgboost4j version 0.72](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/ml.dmlc/xgboost4j/0.72)
- [xgboost4j-spark version 0.72](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/ml.dmlc/xgboost4j-spark/0.72)

I have also downloaded the [xgboost wrapper file sparkxgb.zip](https://github.com/dmlc/xgboost/files/2161553/sparkxgb.zip) to the path `~/Softwares/sparkxgb.zip`.

## My jupyter notebook first cell

```py
import xgboost
print(xgboost.__version__) # 1.2.0


import os
os.environ['PYSPARK_SUBMIT_ARGS'] = '--jars xgboost4j-spark-0.72.jar,xgboost4j-0.72.jar pyspark-shell'

HOME = os.path.expanduser('~')

import findspark
findspark.init(HOME + "/Softwares/spark-3.0.0-bin-hadoop2.7")

import pyspark
from pyspark.sql.session import SparkSession
from pyspark.sql.types import *
from pyspark.ml.feature import StringIndexer, VectorAssembler
from pyspark.ml import Pipeline
from pyspark.sql.functions import col

spark = SparkSession\
        .builder\
        .appName("PySpark XGBOOST Titanic")\
        .getOrCreate()

spark.sparkContext.addPyFile(HOME + "/Softwares/sparkxgb.zip")
print(pyspark.__version__) # 3.0.0
# this does not give any error
# Computer: MacOS
```

## This cell gives errror

```py
from sparkxgb import XGBoostEstimator
```

## Error

```py
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ImportError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-7-cf2ff39c26f4> in <module>
----> 1 from sparkxgb import XGBoostEstimator

/private/var/folders/tb/7xdk9scs79j9hxzcl3l_s6k00000gn/T/spark-1cf282a4-f3f2-42b3-a064-6bbd8751489e/userFiles-abca5e59-5af3-4b3d-a3bc-edc2973e9995/sparkxgb.zip/sparkxgb/__init__.py in <module>
     18 
     19 from sparkxgb.pipeline import XGBoostPipeline, XGBoostPipelineModel
---> 20 from sparkxgb.xgboost import XGBoostEstimator, XGBoostClassificationModel, XGBoostRegressionModel
     21 
     22 __all__ = ["XGBoostEstimator", "XGBoostClassificationModel", "XGBoostRegressionModel",

/private/var/folders/tb/7xdk9scs79j9hxzcl3l_s6k00000gn/T/spark-1cf282a4-f3f2-42b3-a064-6bbd8751489e/userFiles-abca5e59-5af3-4b3d-a3bc-edc2973e9995/sparkxgb.zip/sparkxgb/xgboost.py in <module>
     19 from pyspark.ml.param import Param
     20 from pyspark.ml.param.shared import HasFeaturesCol, HasLabelCol, HasPredictionCol, HasWeightCol, HasCheckpointInterval
---> 21 from pyspark.ml.util import JavaMLWritable, JavaPredictionModel
     22 from pyspark.ml.wrapper import JavaEstimator, JavaModel
     23 from sparkxgb.util import XGBoostReadable

ImportError: cannot import name 'JavaPredictionModel' from 'pyspark.ml.util' (/Users/poudel/Softwares/spark-3.0.0-bin-hadoop2.7/python/pyspark/ml/util.py)
```

## Questions

- How to fix the error and run xgboost in pyspark?

Maybe I have not placed downloaded jar files to correct path. (I have them placed in my working directory where I have jupyter notebook file). Do I need to place these files somewhere else? I assume jupyter automatically loads the path `.` and sees these jar files but I may be wrong.

If any good samaritan has already ran xgboost in pyspark, their help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

This question was asked almost 6 months ago but still no solution were provided.
Even I was facing the same issue for past few days, and finally I got solution so would like to share with all my folks.
By now you might have also got solution but I thought it would be better if I share so that you or in future any one can get benefits from this solution.

You can get rid of this error in two ways,

1. JavaPredictionModel has been removed from latest version of pyspark, so your can downgrad pyspark to let say version 2.4.0, then error will resolve.
   But by doing this you might have to follow all the structure of old pyspark version only like OneHotEncoder can not be used for multiple features at same time you have to do that one-by-one.

   **!pip install pyspark==2.4.0**
2. The second and best solution is to modify sparkxgb codes, like you can import JavaPredictionModel from pyspark.ml.wrapper, so you don't need to downgrad your pyspark.

   **from pyspark.ml.wrapper import JavaPredictionModel**

P.S. Pardon me for not following the answer standards.

Comment: I tried your option 2. 

    from sparkxgb import XGBoostEstimator

Now I am getting error:


    TypeError: Cannot create a consistent method resolution
    order (MRO) for bases object, JavaModel, JavaPredictionModel, JavaMLWritable, XGBoostReadable

Did you make other changes in addition to the package rename for JavaPredictionModel ?

Comment: @vecktorking , I am getting same error following option 2. Did you get the solution for that? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

There are some problem with your versions. I know decision of similar problem fot catboost_spark. So i had a problem with versions (catboost_spark_version)

You need to go to https://catboost.ai/en/docs/installation/spark-installation-pyspark

> Get the appropriate catboost_spark_version (see available versions at Maven central).
>
> Choose the appropriate spark_compat_version (2.3, 2.4 or 3.0) and scala_compat_version (2.11 or 2.12).
>
> Just add the catboost-spark Maven artifact with the appropriate spark_compat_version, scala_compat_version and catboost_spark_version to spark.jar.packages Spark config parameter and import the catboost_spark package:

1. So you go to https://search.maven.org/search?q=catboost-spark and
   choose version (for example catboost-spark_3.3_2.12)
2. Then copy "Artifact ID". In this case is "catboost-spark_3.3_2.12:1.1.1"
3. Then paste it to your config parameter

And you will get something like this:

```
sparkSession = (SparkSession.builder
.master('local[*]')
.config("spark.jars.packages", "ai.catboost:catboost-spark_3.3_2.12:1.1.1")
.getOrCreate())

import catboost_spark
```

and it will works :)